# Equivalent expression for "tl;dr" in Portuguese?

Tags: expressões

In English (Internet) `tl;dr` is an abbreviation for *Too long; didn't read*, used to indicate that what follows is either a summary of the overly long text.

Does there exist any equivalent expression in Portuguese (Europe/Brazilian)?

---

No Inglês (Internet) `tl; dr` é uma abreviatura para *Too long; didn't read*, que deve significar algo como *Muito longo, não li*. É usado para indicar um resumo do texto excessivamente longo.

Existe alguma expressão equivalente em Portugues (Europeu/Brasileiro)?

Comment: Eu não conheço nenhuma, alias no SOpt usa-se muito o `tl;dr`...

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim é notado, este é um dos motivos, pois vejo muitos usando mas a maioria não entende. Acho que a palavra "resumindo" vai ser o mais próximo.

Comment: Quem sabe **ml;nl** :P

Comment: @Bacco muito longo, não li? Parece legal hehehe

Answer (score 8):

There is no equivalent expression to `tl;dr` in Portuguese, as far as I know, but there are some expressions with similar meaning:

`Curto e grosso` - literal translation "Short and thick". What follows should be a direct explanation, no frills, possibly for thick-minded people.

`Longo demais` - "Too long". Just a complaint.

`Em resumo:` - "To summarize:" or "Summing up". What follows should be a summary of what was said before.

`Resumo da ópera`. Rarely used (who knows [opera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera) nowadays?). Used to cut a longer explanation and just tell the gist of the rest after it.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `"resumindo"` that is like `in a nutshell`, it says you are summarizing something. Thats the only expression that can be closer to `tl;tr`

Comment: Yes the word "short" for the closest we have +1

Comment: @Guilherme, pois então, hora de criar um tl;dr;pt;br: `rs;rs => resumo;resumido` :)

Comment: @brasofilo na verdade nem necessita de um resumo;resumido, apenas de um "resumindo" já indica que você está resumindo de fato o assunto.

Comment: @MatheusSilva você não entendeu `rs;rs` é uma ideia do brasofilo de criar uma nova "referencia web" ao menos pra ser usada no StackOverflow em Portugues :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento a, desculpe :)

Comment: TL;TR is kind of trolling long texts, no matter what they are good or bad... I am afraid it is not related to "resumindo". Also it is not responding to the question that is related to "tr;dr". I am downvoting this, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

There is no equivalent acronym to `tl;dr`, at least in Brazilian Portuguese. The closest thing in use in social networks is `preguiça`, which in English means `laziness`, but in this context means "Your post/text is so long/boring/annoying that I won't spend  my finite time and energy going through it." `Preguiça` usually has a negative connotation, I don't think the same holds true to `tl;dr`.

Finally, just like `lol` and `wtf`, I have seen `tl;dr` used in Portuguese-only threads multiple times, albeit by people who could also speak English.

Comment: Thanks!! But I've never seen the word "preguiça" being used to situations like this one.

Answer (score 2):

Too long commentary to [Eduardo França](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/340/eduardo-fran%c3%a7a). In Brazilian Portuguese, "Preguiça" is usually something **in the person** (in this case the reader) that may prevent doing something; the "tl;dr" expression makes assumptions referring to something **in the environment** (as far as I know, in the writer); text was too long, so it is not related to the reader willingness. Of course, when no explicit criteria is used, and depending on the circumstances, someone claiming a "text was too long" might be revealing lack of will or laziness when the text in fact was good and justifiably long.

Considering this previous observation, I would say yes, "preguiça" could be used to tag the behaviour of people claiming, unjustifiably, that a text was tl;dr. However, I would say no, "preguiça" is not the expression the OP is looking; as a correlate of tl;dr.

Now, answering the question, as long as a similar expression in Brazilian Portuguese can't be found, I would translate tl;dr as follows:

- [por ser] muito longo, [por isso o texto] não [foi] lido.
- [o texto era] demasiadamente longo para ser lido.
- [o texto era] injustificadamente longo para ser lido.

Those translations emphasizes the length of the text and not the felling of the reader. On the contrary, the following emphasizes the reader, the person:

- Muito longo, mas eu simplesmente não quis ler o texto.
- Muito longo, mas não li o texto por pura preguiça, [embora o texto fosse interessante e bom].

Comment: Or *Muito longo, não li* :)

Comment: Eu estava dando alternativas, ao estilo tradução de títulos de filmes brasileiros :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such abbreviation in ptPT (European Portuguese). However, the Portuguese often use those kinds of English abbreviations, such as *LOL*, *WTF*, *idk*, and so on.

If you want to write a resume then you can either write 'Resumo' or 'Em poucas palavras' (in a few words) or 'Resumindo' (shortening) to start the end of a resumé.

However, I don't know any European Portuguese expression more populary used to begin a resume or a shortened text, other than 'Em poucas palavras' (in a few words).

**The examples I can give you:**

- "Em poucas palavras, ele não quis o emprego."
- "In a few words, he didn't want the job."

Instead of explaining or telling the whole story, I summarize that into a single line to state the conclusion.

Comment: Thanks!! But I have not asked abbreviations, but a expression, in other words can be a abbreviation or any other type of expression. :)

Comment: resumé é currículo, não resumo